# Base64 encoded string to file

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I have a base64 encoded string.

How can I write this base64 encoded string to a file?

Comment: As a first pointer, check out MSDN's documentation on the **XmlTextreader**'s **ReadBase64** Method...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.readbase64.aspx

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Try this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\yourfile", Convert.FromBase64String(yourBase64String));
```

Comment: I want to save pdf file(300kb) Convert in base 64 string. this file is  saved proper but not open properly. Another solutions of the large file??