# Webapi controller parameters are null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I have reactjs component that sends a PUT request to a web api controller, however the received object (tenant) is null.  I could attach the remote debugger and noticed this.

my react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper.js';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {TenantId: '', TenantUrl: '', TenantPassword: '' };
    this.handleChangeTenantUrl = this.handleChangeTenantUrl.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantPassword = this.handleChangeTenantPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantId= this.handleChangeTenantId.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  };


  handleChangeTenantUrl(event){
    this.setState({TenantUrl: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantPassword(event){
    this.setState({TenantPassword: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantId(event){
    this.setState({TenantId: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("TenantId", this.state.TenantId);
    formData.append("TenantUrl", this.state.TenantUrl);
    formData.append("TenantPassword", this.state.TenantPassword);

    const options = {
      method: 'put',
      data: formData,
      config: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    };

    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          this.setState({ data: responseJson });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  upload(e){
      let data = new FormData();
      //Append files to form data
      let files = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append('files', files[i], files[i].name);
      }      
  }

  render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;

    return (
      <div>
        <LayoutWrapper>
        <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
        <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
          <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
            <Box
              title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
              subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
            >
              <ContentHolder>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                  TenantId:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantId} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantId} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantUrl:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantUrl} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantUrl} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantPassword:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantPassword} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantPassword} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Certificate:
                  <input onChange = { e => this.upload(e) } type = "file" id = "files" ref = { file => this.fileUpload } />
                </label>             
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
              </ContentHolder>
            </Box>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </LayoutWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My tenant controller Put method

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTenant([FromBody]Tenant tenant)
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            var contentType = "";
            var content = new byte[0];
            await base.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            if (provider.Contents.Count > 0)
            {
                contentType = provider.Contents[0].Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                content = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }


            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageKey"].ToString());
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificatesContainer"].ToString());

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content);
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);

            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            tenant.content = content;
            tenant.CertificatePath = blockBlob.Uri;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var added = await tenantStore.AddAsync(tenant);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
        }
```

and the tenant POCO

```
 public class Tenant
    {
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string TenantUrl { get; set; }
        public Uri CertificatePath { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePassword { get; set; }

        public byte[] content { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

stacktrace:

```
"   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser.ValidateArguments(HttpContent content, Int64 maxMessageSize, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser..ctor(HttpContent content, MultipartStreamProvider streamProvider, Int64 maxMessageSize, Int32 maxBodyPartHeaderSize)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TenantManagementWebApi.Controllers.TenantController.<PutTenant>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\levm3\source\repos\TenantManagementWebApi\Controllers\TenantController.cs:line 48
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

I guess my problem is in react and not in the webapi, how do I change my react component to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of sending multipart form data you should send JSON object to
>   server from react component

this will make your life easier.

**Example**

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

**Reference:-** [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

And in c# change this

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTenant(Tenant tenant)
```

**Update:- How to upload a file to Server**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript), you have 3 options

but I would prefer converting to base64 if you don't have very frequent communication.

So you have to follow this steps

1. Convert file to base64 string refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)
2. Send that base64 string to the server with other data
3. receive the file as the base64 string on the server side
4. Decode base64 string on the server refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588306/base64-encoded-string-to-file) for c#

Comment: you have not explianed about the most important piece, the File Upload, please provide a sample of how to send json data, and at the same time handle fhe file upload as I need. thanks

Comment: not a bad idea, so basically the fileitself would be a string parameter (base 64). I like this way